# Is it safe to extend a static member class with another static memberclass?

Tags: java, overriding

I want to make one parent exception class of static type - ParentException
and inherit it inside another class. I found the benefits in making the ParentException as a general custom exception class which makes my code cleaner.

```
interface I{
 public void method throws ParentException {}

}

 public abstract class Parent implements I {
  public static class ParentException extends Exception{}
 }

public class Child extends Parent {
 public static class ChildException extends ParentException{
 //..
 }
 @Override
 public void method throws ChildException {
 // using ChildException allowed here, as Exception can be more specific in overriding 
    }
   }

  }
```

Comment: Why do you think it is a good idea to make exception classes static?

Comment: First, Static is always encouraged. Second, doing this will let me use my interface more and more.

Comment: "static is encouraged" - where did you hear that? In my experience most uses of static are obsolete or should be better embedded into a proper OOP structure. Especially if done by beginners. There are only a few cases of good static usage (utility classes, constants and similar). Though you use static here for nesting classes, not necessarily for "static members/methods".

Comment: Is there a specific reason you nest classes in the first place? You may also want to organize your projects by using modules and packages instead of having nested classes.

Comment: Joshua Bloch in Item 22 of his book "Effective Java Second Edition". Please search on google, why static member classes are good. Loose coupling to cite one advantage.

Comment: Can you pinpoint the exact citation?

Comment: No Problem. Here you may read it.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238782/why-prefer-non-static-inner-classes-over-static-ones

@Fidlor, what runtime issues do you want to point out here. It is safe, I think.

Comment: I guess you are referring to this: _"If you declare a member class that does not require access to an enclosing instance, always put the static modifier in its declaration, making it a static rather than a nonstatic member class."_ - Well, he's right. But you shouldn't use member classes here _at all_ in the first place.

Comment: thanks, @Fildor. Yes, now you get it correctly. I think the above implementations to use custom exception class is beautiful, what do you say?

Comment: Well, checked exceptions are a whole topic on itself. But why in the world would you use inner classes? What is the point in that? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Fildor, Top Class may be used instead. But I want to know what if? What if i use it inner static way. What if, i intend not to make a Top member class for this? Why not, should I handle the custom exceptions in m package using inner static classes? Truly, I do not see any harm. But I want to take the opinion of experts.

Comment: Ignoring the issue of why you are doing this .... I can't think of any technical reason why it wouldn't work.  (I'm not sure where "safety" comes into this.  It either works or it doesn't.)

Comment: @StephenC Agreed. I just wanted this answer. Apology for the word "safety". i meant, whether I may fall into any runtime issue because of this. I think, it is a correct approach too.

Comment: let me explain the scenario:

1. There is an already written code, that I am not allowed to touch (except extending this ChildExceptionClass with the ParentException). Pupose of this package: It deals with DB calls.
2. I need to write another package that reads from service and not DB. But the method signatures will be almost same.
So, I want to now introduce
2.1 an interface, having the common method signatures
2.2 another custom Exception for this new package using the common interface
2.3 both custom exceptions will extend one common ParentException that i'l declare in Interface.

Comment: This way my interface method has one Parent exception in throws clause in signature.
And, the Child classes will have their own ChildExceptions.
And, I do not have to change much in already made package(else I need to remove the static custom exception class, it contains and bring up the Top Exception class everywhere). Hope it explains.

Comment: What is your question then? Run tests to make sure you get the expected behavior. If you (and your team) are happy with it then why care if random strangers on the internet like your design?

Comment: @Fildor It is a very basic question but I could not find a single appropriate reference on stack overflow where a static member class extends another static member class. 
1. Since it is very basic, it gives me doubts whether there might be any issues with this design.
2. I ran test cases, and I worked well.
3. But, I still want to take a second opinion.
I am also sure that this citation of code will let others think more on this and provide any other better design with static member classes.

Again, it was for understanding the pros and cons of this design.

Comment: The question is still open for the experts who would like to provide more on this design.

Comment: The difference between static inner class and instance (non-static) inner class is you do not need to create an Outer class and then use it's instance when you want to create a static inner class. But if you want to create an instance of non-static inner class you have to create the outer class first, then you have to use it to create inner class, for example new Outer().new InstanceInner() and new Outer.StaticInner(). And whenever you can access the inner class, you can extend it. It helps to pack the related things together, usually someone from outside does not need to know.

Comment: Yes, it helps to pack the things internally. Someone from outside does need to know. We see such implementations in java.util.collections package. Map.Entry is one of the example.